# Nvidia driver for kernel 4.4.1? Any luck, anyone?

Tags: kernel-modules, nvidia

After some challenges getting Kernel 4.4.1 (Ubuntu 15.10 ) to work on my hardware (MSI GS40 Phantom laptop) it looks like I have to go back to Noveau as the nVidia driver doesn't work.

Has anybody any luck with getting nvidia to work on 4.4.1 (happy to recompile kernel if necessary).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You should also state which nvidia driver version you tried. Here on Arch Linux I have Linux 4.4.1 with nvidia 361.28 running without issues. I assume, though, that 358.16 only works with linux 4.3.x

Comment: Of course. I was trying 361.28 (64 bit), but any version that works for 4.4.1 is fine with me!